# Load 2D array variables into class intances

Tags: java, arrays

I'm lacking the knowledge on 2d arrays and I need help populating data from an array into a few class variables.

So I have simple product class that looks like this:

```java
public class Product{
    int prodID;
    String prodName;
    Double prodCost;
    int prodQuantity;
```

I also have a class with two methods:

1. Taking a CSV and converting it to an array - done
2. Taking variables from the array and adding them to the appropriate variables - not finished

The array/CSV looks like this:

**product ID | product name | product cost | quantity**

-----001----- | -----item1----- | -----5.99----- | -----3-----

-----002----- | -----item2----- | -----2.99----- | -----5-----

I want to write code that iterates over the array, and creates `Product` instances for each line. Eventually I will have a list of products. I can always assume the CSV is in fixed format so there will always only be 4 variables as seen in the table above.

So this is what I have so far:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class productsImport extends Product {

    public static List<List<String>> csvToArray() {
        String fileName = "c:\\temp\\test.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        // this gives you a 2-dimensional array of strings
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner inputStream;

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(file);

            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String line = inputStream.next();
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                // this adds the currently parsed line to the 2-dimensional string array
                lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lines;
    }

    public static void mapToProdcut(List<List<String>> lines){
        for (List<String> line : lines) {
            Product p = new Product();
            for (String value : line) {
                ???
            }
        }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        csvToArray();
        mapToProdcut(csvToArray());
    }
}
```

The first method converts the CSV to an array. The second method is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to iterate properly over the array to make sure that `p.prodID`, `p.prodName`, `p.prodCost` and `p.prodQuantity` are all populated with the corresponding column. I want to skip over the first row, because it will always show the field titles and they're not relevant.

Any help with this would be great :)

Comment: You should remove the inner loop and simply get values like `prodID = line.get(0)` and so on. If you want to skip first row, it would actually be easier with a regular "for loop" and not "for-each loop".

Comment: @Amongalen thanks for the answer. I went for something like this to test out what it prints: `for (int i = 1; i< lines.size(); i++) { 
            System.out.println(lines.get(i));
        }`

But how do I differentiate the variables? It gets the whole line but I need one variable in that line, then the next variable in that line as so forth.

Comment: As you said `lines.get(i)` is a whole line - it is still a List of Strings, so you can get specific values as you would with any list.

Comment: @Amongalen Is it still relevant if I'm not looking for specific strings? I just want to add whatever string there is in the first cell, then the second. Am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to create a constructor that takes all variables as parameters to simplify the code

```
public Product(int prodID, String prodName, Double prodCost, int prodQuantity) {
    this.prodID = prodID;
    this.prodName = prodName;
    this.prodCost = prodCost;
    this.prodQuantity = prodQuantity;
}
```

If you are running Java 8 you can use streams

```
List<Product> products = 
lines.stream()
    .skip(1)
    .map(s -> new Product(
        Integer.valueOf(s.get(0)), 
        s.get(1), 
        Double.valueOf(s.get(2)), Integer.valueOf(s.get(3))
        )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise you can use a `for` loop

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    List<String> s = lines.get(i);
    Product product = new Product(
        Integer.valueOf(s.get(0)), 
        s.get(1), 
        Double.valueOf(s.get(2)), 
        Integer.valueOf(s.get(3)));
    products.add(product);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it would be as simple as this? So you basically load each line into a string `s` and then get the variable inside of it and put in the corresponding object of the class?

Comment: @DanielBeilin No, s is not a string. It's a list of string that correspond to one row in the csv file